# R group_by with ranges (or aggregate)

Tags: r

I have a table like this :

```
City; Class; Number;  Sum
 BE ;    01;    734; 4711
 BE ;    02;    896; 4711
 BE ;    03;   1258; 4711
 BE ;    04;    980; 4711
 BE ;    05;    543; 4711
 BE ;    06;    192; 4711
 BE ;    07;     69; 4711
 BE ;    08;     20; 4711
 BE ;    09;     14; 4711
 BE ;    10;      4; 4711
 BE ;    12;      1; 4711
 FR ;    01;   1213;14258
 FR ;    02;   2217;14258
 FR ;    03;   3369;14258
 FR ;    04;   4037;14258
 FR ;    05;   2117;14258
 FR ;    06;    774;14258
 FR ;    07;    301;14258
 FR ;    08;    124;14258
 FR ;    09;     62;14258
 FR ;    10;     21;14258
 FR ;    11;     11;14258
 FR ;    12;      4;14258
 FR ;    13;      2;14258
 FR ;    14;      3;14258
 FR ;    16;      3;14258
```

I would like to "group by" it in 8 ranges of the "Class" variable:

range 1 = "01", range 2 = "02", range 3 = "03", range 4 = "04", range 5 = "05", and 3 ranges of several values : range 6 = "06", "07, "08", "09, "10",
range 7 = "11", "12", "13", "14", "15",
range 8 = "16", "17", "18", "19", "20".

Is it possible to do that with group_by ?

Variables "City" and "Class" are character format.

Thank you very much for any help.

The output table should look like that :

```
City; Range; Number;  Sum;
 BE ;    R1;    734; 4711;
 BE ;    R2;    896; 4711;
 BE ;    R3;   1258; 4711;
 BE ;    R4;    980; 4711;
 BE ;    R5;    543; 4711;
 BE ;    R6;    299; 4711;
 BE ;    R7;      1; 4711;
 FR ;    R1;   1213;14258;
 FR ;    R2;   2217;14258;
 FR ;    R3;   3369;14258;
 FR ;    R4;   4037;14258;
 FR ;    R5;   2117;14258;
 FR ;    R6;   1282;14258;
 FR ;    R7;     20;14258;
 FR ;    R8;      3;14258;
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can recode the 'Class' variable to a new grouping variable and then do the summarizations.  BTW, what kind of summarization you want

Comment: Hello akrun, thank you for replying, I would like the sum of variable "Number". The sum of "Number" must equal the "Sum" variable.

Comment: I didn't get the output table part

Comment: Do you mean the sum of Number by country must equal the Sum variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a `key/value` dataset, `join` with the original dataset, grouped by 'Class' and get the `sum` of 'Number'

```
library(dplyr)
keyDat <- data.frame(Class = sprintf("%02d", 1:20), 
  range = rep(paste0("", 1:8), rep(c(1, 5), c(5, 3))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df1 %>%
   left_join(., keyDat) %>% 
   group_by(City, Range = range) %>%
   summarise(Number = sum(Number), Sum= Sum[1L])
#   City Range Number   Sum
#   <chr> <chr>  <int> <int>
#1    BE     R1    734  4711
#2    BE     R2    896  4711
#3    BE     R3   1258  4711
#4    BE     R4    980  4711
#5    BE     R5    543  4711
#6    BE     R6    299  4711
#7    BE     R7      1  4711
#8    FR     R1   1213 14258
#9    FR     R2   2217 14258
#10   FR     R3   3369 14258
#11   FR     R4   4037 14258
#12   FR     R5   2117 14258
#13   FR     R6   1282 14258
#14   FR     R7     20 14258
#15   FR     R8      3 14258
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(City = c("BE ", "BE ", "BE ", "BE ", "BE ", "BE ", 
"BE ", "BE ", "BE ", "BE ", "BE ", "FR ", "FR ", "FR ", "FR ", 
"FR ", "FR ", "FR ", "FR ", "FR ", "FR ", "FR ", "FR ", "FR ", 
"FR ", "FR "), Class = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
"07", "08", "09", "10", "12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
"07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "16"), Number = c(734L, 
896L, 1258L, 980L, 543L, 192L, 69L, 20L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 1213L, 
2217L, 3369L, 4037L, 2117L, 774L, 301L, 124L, 62L, 21L, 11L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Sum = c(4711L, 4711L, 4711L, 4711L, 4711L, 4711L, 
4711L, 4711L, 4711L, 4711L, 4711L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 
14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 
14258L, 14258L, 14258L)), .Names = c("City", "Class", "Number", 
"Sum"), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4):

using `cut`, you create ranges based on `breaks` values and with it, create a `range` column. Then compute sum of `Number` by grouping `City` variable.

```
df$Range <- cut( as.numeric(df$Class), breaks = c(0, 1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20 ), labels = paste('R', 1:8, sep = '' ))  # create Range column
df$Class <- NULL   # remove Class column
df <- within( df, Sum <- ave(Number, City, FUN = sum ) )  # compute sum by grouping City
df <- within(df, Number <- ave( Number, by = list(City, Range), FUN = sum ) )  # compute sum by grouping City and Range
df[ !duplicated(df), ]  # remove duplicated rows
#    City Number   Sum Range
# 1    BE    734  4711    R1
# 2    BE    896  4711    R2
# 3    BE   1258  4711    R3
# 4    BE    980  4711    R4
# 5    BE    543  4711    R5
# 6    BE    299  4711    R6
# 11   BE      1  4711    R7
# 12   FR   1213 14258    R1
# 13   FR   2217 14258    R2
# 14   FR   3369 14258    R3
# 15   FR   4037 14258    R4
# 16   FR   2117 14258    R5
# 17   FR   1282 14258    R6
# 22   FR     20 14258    R7
# 26   FR      3 14258    R8
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(City = c("BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", 
                              "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", 
                              "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR"),
                     Class = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
                               6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 16L), 
                     Number = c(734L, 896L, 1258L, 980L, 543L, 192L, 69L, 20L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 1213L, 
                                2217L, 3369L, 4037L, 2117L, 774L, 301L, 124L, 62L, 21L, 11L, 
                                4L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
                     Sum = c(4711L, 4711L, 4711L, 4711L, 4711L, 4711L, 4711L, 4711L, 4711L, 4711L,
                             4711L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 
                             14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L, 14258L)),
                .Names = c("City", "Class", "Number", "Sum"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you all for replying, I just edited my post for you to know what is the expected output table. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
df$Class <- factor(df$Class)
levels(df$Class) <- list(R1=c("01"),R2=c("02"),R3=c("03"),R4=c("04"),R5=c("05"),R6=c("06", "07, "08", "09, "10"),R7=c("11", "12", "13", "14", "15"),R8=c("16", "17", "18", "19", "20"))

df_new<-aggregate(df[,3],by=list(df$Class),FUN=sum)
```

Comment: Edited. Thank you.

Comment: So great ! Thank you all for helping, Now, I better understand how work the group_by and aggregate functions. Thanks again. Have a nice day.